# Trying to set cron log, but no is saved on Amazon linux2

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-linux-2

I'm trying to get a success&error log, but no logging. My environment is Amazon Linux 2.

```
/etc/crontab */1 * * * * /home/ec2-user/gaMain.sh >> /var/log/galog.log 2>&1

/var/log/cron (ec2-user) CMD (/home/ec2-user/gaMain.sh >> /var/log/galog.log 2>&1)
```

So, the cron is running.

I expect the output of command `sudo less /var/log/galog.log`, but i I get a error:

> There is no file that name

Comment: I wonder if the cron job does not have permission to write to `/var/log`? Can you try saving the log in `/tmp` instead, and see whether that works?

Comment: Thanks.I tried saving the log in /tmp and I got success. But, I can't change the permission to write a log in /var/log, how can I do?

Comment: It sounds like the cron task is running as a user that is not permitted to write to that location. Either try putting `sudo` in the cron command (`sudo /home/ec2-user/gaMain.sh >> /var/log/galog.log 2>&1`) or create the crontab under the `root` user.